# How to call WordPress plugin function from custom page template?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom WordPress plugin that handles authentication.

There's a function logTheUserIn() inside plugin-name/src/Classes/Auth.php.

I need this function to be run when a user hits a custom WordPress template page (page-authPortal.php), which has this code at the top:

```
    include_once('wp-includes/pluggable.php');
    include_once("wp-content/plugins/ad-auth-bridge/src/Classes/Auth.php");
    print "test";
```

I created a WordPress page titled "authPortal" and it shows the 'test' text, so I know the custom page is being loaded and rendered. Now I just need to fire off logTheUserIn().

I have tried adding shortcodes and actions inside Auth.php:

```
class Auth {
    public function InitHooks() {

  add_shortcode ('authNow', 'logTheUserIn');
  add_action ('authAction', 'logTheUserIn');
```

I've then tried to use the actual shortcode [authNow] inside the WordPress editor, I have also tried do_shortcode and do_action.

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to include or require the plugin fields. They are initially loaded by WordPress.

First, in your template, make sure your plugin is active and the function/class is reachable:

```
if ( function_exists( 'logTheUserIn') ) { 
    logTheUserIn();
}
```

Then fire the function right within your template.

In your case, you might need to check if **class_exists**, then initialize the class